# Why does attribute on a numeric object return NULL?

Tags: r

```
> y <- 1
> attributes(y)
NULL
```

While `class(y)` returns `numeric` and we know that `class` is an attribute, then why does `attributes(y)` return `NULL`?

Comment: "numeric" here is an implicit class (`?class`) and it is not stored as an actual attribute (as -e.g.- in `structure(1, class = "numeric")`)

Comment: From [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Attributes): "All objects except `NULL` _can_ [my emphasis] have one or more attributes attached to them". Note the "_can_". See also [the attribute section in Hadley's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#attributes).

Answer (score 1):

R has many attributes, see `?attributes`:

> Note that some attributes (namely class, comment, dim, dimnames, names, row.names and tsp)...

meaning `attributes` is just one of the bunch. It would be erroneous to expect each object has an `attributes` (`attributes(obj) <- value`) assigned by default.